# Importing/exporting data with Postgres views

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.6

I have a Postgres database that has a well defined interface for importing and exporting data via views. I can `SELECT` from these views and `INSERT` into them fine. Now I would like to be able to export and import data from and to the **views** in bulk.

Instead of `COPY myview TO 'view.tsv'`, which doesn't work, I can do:

```
COPY (SELECT * from myview) TO 'view.tsv'
```

The problem is that I can't import this via `COPY FROM` into the views, I get:

> ERROR: Cannot copy to view 'myview'

I tried `pg_dump` to generate SQL statements, but this only exports the schema, not the data from my view. Is there any way (SQL or command-line) to dump all rows from certain views and import them later into another database?

Comment: do you mean; you can export to csv, but not import?

Comment: please see this [article...](https://launchschool.com/books/sql_first_edition/read/importing_exporting)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already know this information. This works with tables, but I have views.

Comment: Does your view have an `INSTEAD OF` trigger? [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.52.8) "*COPY FROM can be used [...] with views that have INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers.*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Only on PostgreSQL > 10, I'm on 9.6 unfortunately

Comment: Then you are out of luck